# How to mock the data(argument) received for the callback function so that the logic in the callback function can be tested in jest? (e.g. fs.readFile)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, promise, mocking, jestjs

I have function want to do unit testing, for example, it contains:

```
function foo (file, option) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => fs.readFile(file, option, (err, content) => {
        if (err) return reject(new Error(`Failed to read the file: (${file})`));
        else {
            (...some operations, and that is the point for me to test it...)
            return resolve(...some result...);
        }
    }));
}
```

Just right at the beginning of the testing file, I have:

```
jest.mock('fs', () => ({
    readFile : jest.fn(),
}));
const fs = require('fs');
```

The testing logic is something like:

```
test('Should get context as string from the template file', async () => {
    const mockContent = '<a>Hello World</a>';
    fs.readFile.mockReturnValue(mockContent);
    const result = (await foo('test', 'utf8')).then(() => 123);
    //
    expect(result).toEqual(123);
});
```

However, when I try to run the test, it shows:

```
- Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.`
```

I know it is an issue due to unresolved promise from Jest website; but their suggestion is not what I have actually... I recognize my problem is due to `fs.readFile(...)` is replaced by the mocking function which returns `undefined` so that the `new Promise` is never being rejected/resolved (am I correct?!).

My question is how can I do a unit test like this case? I really don't want to fire a I/O event like using a empty file in oder to make it work... Any thoughts?! Thanks!

**/// UPDATE:**
I think a much clear question is how are we mock the data that received by a callback function. In my example it looks like I test against it, but in my real code, what I really want to test is the logic of the callback function.

Comment: The thing is that if you re testing against fs.readFileAsync you should not mock itself. Instead test it with fixture files directly for unit test.

Comment: And working with async functions you need to return a promise or invoke a callback passed from test(xxx, (done)). Btw your mocked jest.fn was not async at all

Comment: Thank you for pointing me out my mocked async function is not async at all!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem, is the way you mock `js.readFile`. `mockReturnValue` just  creates a function that returns something, but you want it to call on of its parameter so you need to use `mockImplementation` to define the mock function by yourself

```
jest.fn().mockImplementation((file, option, cb) => cb(null, mockContent))
```

or

```
jest.fn().mockImplementation((file, option, cb) => cb('Some Error', null))
```

Comment: Oh!!! Thank you so much! I see what stocked me now. What I was doing is the whole function is replaced by the mock function that gives a value but not pass the parameter to my rest of code stayed in the callback. Now I know when to use `mockImplementation`.